# Display city names which start and end with vowels

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to write a SQL query to get city names start and end with vowels only.

Code:

```sql
select distinct city 
from station 
where REGEXP_LIKE (city, '^(a|e|i|o|u).*(a|e|i|o|u)$');
```

This above query gives me the wrong answer. I am using Oracle.

Comment: What is the "wrong answer?"  Can you add sample data here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I am using Hacker rank website. I got the answers

Comment: There are a lot of existing questions and answers about these HackerRank questions, including various combinations of [not] starting and/or ending with vowels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more concise way to write your query using `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$', 'i');
```

The third match parameter `i` tells Oracle to do a case insensitive search.  This frees us from the need of listing out uppercase and lowercase vowels.

Comment: : What is `i` called and how to use not condition in regex if want details does not start with vowels

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: :  How to do this :  Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels.

Comment: Use: `REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$', 'i')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions, but - you can also use `substr` function. For example:

```
SQL> with city (name) as
  2    (select 'BOSTON' from dual union all
  3     select 'ALBUQUERQUE' from dual
  4    )
  5  select name,
  6    case when substr(upper(name), 1, 1) in ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U') and
  7              substr((name), -1)        in ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')
  8         then 'OK'
  9         else 'Not OK'
 10    end as result_1,
 11    --
 12    case when regexp_like(name, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$', 'i') then 'OK'
 13         else 'Not OK'
 14    end as result_2
 15  from city;

NAME        RESULT_1   RESULT_2
----------- ---------- ----------
BOSTON      Not OK     Not OK
ALBUQUERQUE OK         OK

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to write answer for it

**Query :**

```
select distinct city from station where regex_like ( city,'^(a|e|i|o|u|A|E|I|O|U).*(a|e|i|o|u|A|E|I|O|U)$');
```

Comment: You can write that regex more concisely as `'^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'` and use the `i` flag to ignore case.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson : What if want not contain vowels then how to add not

Comment: Try `'^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$'`.